# Spring Boot Filter is not getting invoked if remove @component in filter class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have two endpoints, /health and /save. I don't want to invoke MyFilter for /health endpoint.
Below is the code

```
@Component
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        // do something

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends DefaultSecurityConfig {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().addFilterAfter(new MyFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        super.configure(webSecurity);
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/health/**");
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

The problem is if I remove @component from MyFilter, the filter is not getting invoked for any endpoint and if I put it back it is getting invoked in both endpoints. How can I make it applicable for only /health endpoint ?

Comment: Define an `@Bean` method returning your filter (instead of using `@Component`) and add an additional `FilterRegistrationBean` to select the URL to which is should react. If this needs to be part of the Spring Security filter chain check the URL inside your filter and decide if you need to do 1 thing or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just on `// do something` part, check if requested url is metrics and only do your actions if it is not. The information is readily available in `HttpServletRequest` object.

I'm not sure if there are any more straight-forward ways of doing it. Using a FilterRegistrationBean will only allow you to add urls to include, not urls to exclude.

If you do think that you will only have these two endpoints, you can of course use FilterRegistrationBean to only add your save endpoint:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> myFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new MyFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/save");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

In that case you could remove the Component annotation.

Comment: Thanks. But In future there will be more endpoints apart from /save.. So do we need to add everything to this ?

Comment: @sagarkancherla did you read the first part of my answer? "Just on // do something part, check if requested url is metrics and only do your actions if it is not. The information is readily available in HttpServletRequest object.".